# Spring boot @Inject proxy resolves to null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm refactoring an existing application to use Spring Boot. The issues I've faced here are generally of the type "why is this not working anymore".

I have three packages
- nl.myproject.boot
- nl.myproject
- nl.myproject.rest

My current problem is that *all* `@Service`s that I `@Inject` in a `@RESTController` resolve to null when a method is called on them. 
The service and dao are part of the nl.myproject package and the reason it's not nl.myproject.core is a legacy issue.

A related issue is that my @Configuration components don't seem to be loaded through `@ComponentScan` and I have to import them manually. I also had to exclude Test configuration to prevent Test configs from being loaded, which also seemed weird.

Internal calls from the service layer during start up, such as data preparation works normally. Any such manager is also `@Inject`ed. This is just to say that any of the typical injection mistakes such as manual instantiation or injecting a class instead of an interface don't apply.

I'd also be grateful for debugging tips. My Java has gotten a little rusty.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {
        "nl.myproject", 
        "nl.myproject.boot", 
        "nl.myproject.dao",
        "nl.myproject.service",
        "nl.myproject.webapp"},
    excludeFilters= {   
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.REGEX,pattern={".*Test.*"}),
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.REGEX,pattern={".*AppConfig"})
    }
)
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Import({
    JPAConfig.class,
    RestConfig.class,
    BootConfig.class
})
public class Startup {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Startup.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/json/tags")
public class JsonTagController extends JsonBaseController {

    @Inject
    TagManager tagMgr;
```

```
public interface TagManager extends BaseManager<Tag,Long> {
[...]
}

@Service("tagManager")
public class TagManagerImpl extends BaseManagerImpl<Tag, Long> implements
        TagManager {

    @Inject
    TagDao dao;
[...]
```

Comment: Try `@Autowired` instead of `@Inject`

Comment: I will but why should it make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

`@Inject` *is a annotation specified by JSR-330 (standard) whereas* `@Autowired` is *annotation specified by **Spring***.

**They just do the same dependency injection. You can both of them in the same code.**

Just the modification (separation of the concerns) you need :

```
public interface TagManager {
[...]
}

@Service
public class TagManagerImpl implements TagManager {

    @Inject
    private TagDao dao;

    // inject that service rather than extending
    @Inject
    private BaseManager<Tag,Long> baseManager;
}

public interface BaseManager<Tag,Long> {
[...]
}

@Service
public class BaseManagerImpl<Tag,Long> implements BaseManager<Tag,Long> {
  ....
}
```

***Just one thing you do for checking, just modify to*** `basePackages= {"nl.myproject"}` ***- just provide only base package, that's enough for spring to scan the components in every package.***

Hope this may help :)

Comment: Cheers, but why is this necessary (this would require a lot of refactoring and it worked before in another context)?

Comment: @Marc I think every class should have a specific role. It makes it easier for the developer to understand.